# ORA-00904: "CREATEXML": invalid identifier

Tags: xml, oracle

I want to retrieve value from XML data stored as CLOB in Oracle 11g DB.

I tried

```sql
create table xml_test(
  id number,
  xml_text clob
);

insert into xml_test 
values(
  1, to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rule name="name"></rule>')
);

select createXML(xml_text) from xml_test;
```

([SQL fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1548e/1))

([SQL fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1548e/17))

What am I doing wrong?

According this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/t_xml.htm#BABHCHHJ) this should work with both CLOB and VARCHAR2, right?

My goal is to retrieve @name via XPath

Note: Please, this SQL fiddle example is just an idea, unfortunately it's not working online (`NullPointerException`), it works fine in my DB (up to `createXML` functions in queries)

Comment: Strange, the fiddle works for me... With the error you describe.

Comment: I found, that comment cannot be before first statement, so it's fixed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateXML() is not a global SQL function.  It is a static method on the XMLTYPE object.  Try this:

```
select xmltype.createXML(xml_text) from xml_test;
```

See intro in the doc, "XMLType is a system-defined opaque type for handling XML data. It has *predefined member functions* on it to extract XML nodes and fragments."

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly as I needed. I tried to google examples but didn't find it. Also `xmltype.extract(xmltype.createXML(xml_text), '/rule/@name')` works fine now.